# Delayed_job - job failing - need error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am using delayed_job to run background processes.  It works fine but then suddenly fails a job for no apparent reason (the job suddenly disappears from the jobs queue).  There is nothing printed in the delayed_job log other than failure.  Is there a way to get better logging or at least print out an error message?

s

Comment: I was having a similar problem a while back. Unfortunately I don't have the code with me right now. However, I do remember that I had found the solution in the wiki of one of the `delayed_job` forks by collective idea. Heres the [link](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Common-problems).

Comment: Have you tested that the job works fine without delayed_job? That would be my first port of call…

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, it works completely fine but sometimes just does not work.  I have it working perfectly locally and I got failed jobs to log, but I had no luck on the server.